# How to upload a PDF to server that is already embedded in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I already have the file opened in an iframe.

```
<object id="pdf"
        type="application/pdf" 
        data="~/Content/documents/DD2981.pdf" 
        width="1000" 
        height="750">
</object>
```

It opens in Chrome, Firefox and IE with no problems.

This is a fillable PDF intended to be filled out by multiple users.

How do I upload the fillable file (with the data that the user filled out) to the server? I want to share this PDF with other users.

EDIT: I've tried using this function here:

```
 var pdf = document.getElementById('pdf');

$('input[type=submit]').click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData(pdf);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/pdf',
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            // The file was uploaded successfully...  
           console.log('File was uploaded.');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // there was an error.  
            console.log('Whoops! There was an error in the request.');
        }
    });
});
```

I also have a controller in .NET MVC

```
[Route("pdf")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PDF(object form)
{
     return null;
}
```

So the AJAX call hits the route but there isn't any data  in the form.

Comment: This doesn’t sound like you made much of an effort to research this yourself first … https://www.google.com/search?q=fill+out+pdf+form+and+send+to+server+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @CBroe I've updated. I have a controller that I hit. I've tried using Web API's FormData class to get the data, but it doesn't have anything in it.

Comment: Well that is not surprising, because the FormData constructor expects the reference to an HTML `form` element as parameter, whereas you are trying to feed it an object.

Comment: @CBroe So what datatype should I use? I've tried using .NET's FormCollection class as a parameter. Still no good.

Comment: You should start by properly researching this, instead of just trying stuff willy-nilly. This starts with finding out how you can access data filled into a PDF form loaded into an iframe via JavaScript - and _if_ that’s possible at all to begin with. Right now you seem to be operating merely on assumptions here.